# Does leaflet support user defined Layer identifiers

Tags: leaflet, layers

It would be nice to be able to check for a layer presence or remove it without having to keep an explicit reference to it. To that extent I would like to use ad id for the layer that I can compute myself from my data. Is this feasible with leaflet? If no, do you have any clean workaround?

For example with a LayerGroup, the idea is to have a `setId(<String> id)` function that would allow leveraging the native `removeLayer( <String> id )` and `getLayer( <String> id )` methods to work on the LayerGroup content by user defined identifiers. Example below:

```js
marker = L.circleMarker(...);
marker.setId('my_marker_id');
lg = L.layerGroup(...);
lg.addLayer(marker);
...
lg.removeLayer('my_marker_id');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you place all your layers in the same `L.featureGroup` or `L.layerGroup`, like this:

```js
group = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
L.marker([34.07,-118.29]).addTo(group);
L.marker([34.06,-118.28]).addTo(group);
[etc., etc....]
```

you can iterate over the layers using the `.eachLayer` method. This will allow you to create a property of any name you like (say, `layerID`) and assign a unique value to each layer:

```js
var tempID = 1;
group.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  layer.layerID = tempID;
  tempID+=1;
  layer.bindPopup('Layer ID: ' + layer.layerID);
});
```

To access that ID later, you can use `.eachLayer` again to find the matching feature and perform whatever task you like on it. For instance:

```js
deleteFromGroupByID = function (group, ID) {
    group.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    if (layer.feature.properties.layerID === ID) {
        group.removeLayer(layer);
    }
  });
}
```

Here's an example fiddle of this at work:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/6aLmzwmg/

If you are using GeoJSON, it is probably best to store this value in the feature properties instead, as that's what they were designed for. In the above code, you'd just replace `layer.layerID` with `layer.feature.properties.layerID`. Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/oe61fkg0/

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice workaround. So there is no way to leverage the native removeLayer( <String> id ) and getLayer( <String> id ) function for it?

Comment: The `<String> id` refers to the variable name to which a layer is assigned. For instance, if you create a marker with `var mk1 = L.marker(...)`, then you can remove it using `map.removeLayer(mk1)`. But I gathered you were trying to avoid that (unless you meant something else by "explicit reference"?).

Comment: Then I am missing what is the difference between "<String> id" and "ILayer" as parameters since I took for granted that ILayer means a variable holding an object implementing the ILayer interface

Comment: No, actually, I was mistaken. The variable name refers to an `ILayer`, so my answer is indeed using that method, not the `<String> id`. The `id` actually refers to the internal `_leaflet_id` of the layer, which you can access using `L.stamp`. For instance, `L.stamp(marker)` will return the value of `marker._leaflet_id`, and `map.removeLayer(L.stamp(marker))` will remove the marker. However, manually changing the value of `marker._leaflet_id` would break things so that you wouldn't be able to use `removeLayer` (or any leaflet functions at all) on `marker`.

Comment: @nathansnider I think @a1an refers to **Layer Group** methods `removeLayer` and `getLayer`, which can accept the layer's internal id. Map equivalent `removeLayer` do not.

Comment: @ghybs, you are of course correct: `group.removeLayer(L.stamp(marker))` will work, while `map.removeLayer(L.stamp(marker))` will not.